# Passing a param works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, heroku, controller

For some reason, Heroku doesnt pass the param, which gives me a NoMethod error.

This is my controller create action:

```
def create
  # @stock = Stock.new(params[:data].keys, params[:data].values)
  @user = current_user
  @data = params["data"]
  @data.each do |d|
    @stock = Stock.create(my_params(d))
    if @stock.altas == nil && @stock.bajas == nil
      @stock.destroy
    else
      @stock.save
    end
    @item = Item.find(@stock.item_id)
    if @stock.altas != nil
      @item.quantity =  @item.quantity + @stock.altas
      @item.save
    end
    if @stock.bajas != nil
      @item.quantity = @item.quantity - @stock.bajas
      @item.save
    end
  end
  # ItemMailer.reporte_diario_email(@user).deliver_now

  redirect_to change_path, notice: 'Cambio en el inventario creado.'

end
```

The form passes the params["data"], this is my log on localhost, showing that the param passed:

```
Processing by StocksController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>
"BB/8I4Bypwa8aga8x7wCi6QWF2I9tPTuWbIitYpdpESCvOeFfPnDuaf7PjFYkjuzuz6N45t9phdbVZ1QNB3DeA==", "data"=>[{"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"1"}, {"altas"=>"5", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"5"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"3"}, 
{"altas"=>"2", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"2"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"",
"item_id"=>"4"}], "commit"=>"Update"}
```

And this is the log on heroku:

```
Processing by StocksController#create as HTML
 2016-10-25T23:23:32.440253+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"wye0t6tc1BQV15WgQsoVsnvSuwMwA8bCT77JWRqsuRNikVSq+OGhed5oIGczCmdGHl0/f+Y4/KL/YVEOOrzv/g==", "commit"=>"Update"}
```

Finally, this is the form in case needed:

```
 <%= form_tag stocks_path  do %>

  <% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= fields_for 'data[]', @stock do |stock| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= item.nombre %></td>
    <td><center><%= item.material %></center></td>
    <td><center><%= item.marca %></center></td>
    <td><center><%= item.espesor %> mm</center></td>
    <td><center><%= stock.text_field :altas %></center></td>
    <td><center><%= stock.text_field :bajas %></center></td>
    <%= stock.hidden_field :item_id, :value => item.id %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
 <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

As you can see, it's not passing the params["data"] at all, not sure why, since its the same code... any guesses?

On this try, a few minutes later, the param was loaded:

```
  2016-10-25T23:53:24.972488+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/stocks" for  65.34.251.106 at 2016-10-25 23:53:24 +0000
  2016-10-25T23:53:24.980412+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by  StocksController#create as HTML
  2016-10-25T23:53:24.980989+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wye0t6tc1BQV15WgQsoVsnvSuwMwA8bCT77JWRqsuRNikVSq+OGhed5oIGczCmdGHl0/f+Y4/KL/YVEOOrzv/g==", "data"=>[{"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"48"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"49"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"50"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"51"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"52"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"53"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"54"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"55"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"56"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"57"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"58"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"59"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"60"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"61"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"62"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"63"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"64"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"65"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"66"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"67"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"68"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"69"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"70"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"71"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"72"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"73"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"74"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"75"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"76"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"77"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"78"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"79"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"80"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"81"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"82"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"83"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"84"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"85"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"2"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"6"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"3"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"4"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"1"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"86"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"7"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"8"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"9"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"10"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"11"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"12"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"13"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"14"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"15"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"16"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"17"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"18"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"19"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"20"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"21"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"22"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"23"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"24"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"25"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"26"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"27"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"28"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"29"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"30"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"31"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"32"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"33"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"34"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"35"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"36"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"37"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"38"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"39"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"40"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"41"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"42"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"43"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"44"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"1", "item_id"=>"45"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"46"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"87"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"88"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"89"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"90"}, {"altas"=>"", "bajas"=>"", "item_id"=>"47"}], "commit"=>"Update"}
  2016-10-25T23:53:27.334490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/stocks" host=herrajestorino.herokuapp.com request_id=f1bda6e7-6fca-4150-8dae-056de5892991 fwd="65.34.251.106" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2507ms status=302 bytes=1028
```

This is the new action on the controller:

```
def new
 @stock = Stock.new
 @items = Item.all
end
```

Comment: This is even weirder, its random, sometimes it passes the param, and others dont...

Comment: Please post the error message.  First suspicion is that your Heroku database doesn't have any entries in it while your development database does, which is why you're not catching the bug.  Also, you're showing the params for the update action not create.  Try creating a new stock in development and show us the params for `create`ing a new stock, not `update`ing one that exists.

Comment: "Update" is the name of the button, and its not related to the error, regarding the error, is NoMethodError (undefined method "each" for nil class) this is because the param is not passing, i tried a few more times, and one of this times passed the params and saved the change, so i dont thing its code related and its more heroku related...

Comment: @Kelseydh on the question you have on log from localhost passing the params to create the stock, as you can see both says "update" on the commit

Comment: Can you post the controller method you used to initialize the form, as I could see this being a problem if the form is initialized with `@stock` or `@item` being nil.

Comment: try with `params[:data]`

Comment: @Kelseydh the one thats not initializing is data, since its not getting the params.
I changed to [:data] and once again, the first try worked, the 2nd got me the same error because its not passing the params[:data]

Comment: Can you post your `new` controller action as if there is an error there it will affect your `create` action by messing with the params you receive.

Comment: @Kelseydh i just posted it... do you know if there is a limit of characters a param would pass? because i, feeling that this may be the issue...

Comment: Ok, i found the issue, it has something to do with bootstrap table sortable class, if i press the title to put the names in order, then it will give me an error, if i dont, it will pass the params, so any idea why after sorting the param will vanish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed, not sure why, but bootstrap sortable table removes the params once is pressed, thats why it was acting randomly, i didnt notice that sometimes i pressed the button to sort them and others dont, once i figured this out, i remove the sortable class and make the order in the controller instead, and it actually looks better now, this is how the controller changed, in case needed:

```
def new
@stock = Stock.new
@items = Item.all.order(:nombre).order(:material).order(:marca).order(:espesor)
end
```

That fixed it!
thanks a lot for your help!!